# IDE и NetBeans - горячие клавиши

Tags: css, phpstorm, html, netbeans, ide

Может кто вкурсе

Я написал html страницу и задал в ней каждому элементу имя class

В общем теперь мне вручную нужно писать в файл css имена этих классов

Может есть горячие клавиши которые автоматически создадут шаблон css с именами классов присутствующих в html коде?

Comment: Мне кажется, что такой функции быть не должно, поскольку вы говорите о весьма редкой потребности - обычно CSS создается учитывая зависимость вложенности элементов, названия элементов и т.п. А простой список всех классов, мне кажется, крайне мало кому нужен. Вы, однако, можете сделать это сами используя регулярные выражения на удобном для вас языке программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть посмотрите в сторону "шаблонов кода" ?
Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates далее в комбоксе нужный язык и задаете свои сочетания, которых Вам не хватает